# Имеет ли смысл ставить тревогу модератору на парных незарегистрированных пользователей?

Tags: поддержка

[Вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/499622/178988) задан пользователем [user204308](//ru.stackoverflow.com/users/204308/user204308), а [уточняющий ответ](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/499628/178988) (вместо комментария) на него пользователем [user204309](//ru.stackoverflow.com/users/204309/user204309) - обращаю внимание, что номера последовательные, а аватарки одинаковые (я так понимаю, это означает одиковый email):

[image: Автарка]

Нужно ли в таком случае ставить тревогу модератору? Насколько я помню, модератор всё равно не может объединить аккаунты, если он не сотрудник компании.

---

Кстати, если человек так завёл два незарегистрированных аккаунта, то может ли он писать сообщения от первого из них? Или при появлении второго куки первого безвозвратно потерялись и аккаунтом больше нельзя пользоваться?

Comment: Ну вот, похоже, он зарегистрировался?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не знаю, чем бы я мог помочь такому пользователю,  используя возможности модератора.

Возможно, человек не осознает, что его ограничения связаны с отсутствием регистрации. Стоит оставить комментарий, порекомендовать зарегистрироваться и больше не мучаться. Но это может сделать любой участник. :)

Про аватарки догадка вроде бы верная.

Когда тревога все-таки нужна:

- "не является ответом", когда этот пользователь публикует ответом дополнение к вопросу или комментарий.